# Undefined function error for javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous, defined

Here is my code, I don't understand what's wrong.

```
    <script type="text/jquery">

function gettotalAdult()
{
    //Assume form with id="fsd-bucket-calc"
    var theForm = document.forms["fsd-bucket-calc"];
    //Get a reference to the # of Adults & Children
    var quantity = theForm.elements["totalAdult"];
    var caloriesAdult = theForm.elements["caloriesAdult"];
    var adultcalTotal=0;
    //If the totalAdult is not blank
    if(totalAdult.value!="")
    {
        adultcalTotal = parseInt(totalAdult.value)*parseInt(caloriesAdult.value);
    }
return adultcalTotal;
}

function gettotalChild()
{
    //Assume form with id="fsd-bucket-calc"
    var theForm = document.forms["fsd-bucket-calc"];
    //Get a reference to the # of Children
    var totalChild = theForm.elements["totalChild"];
    var caloriesChild = theForm.elements["caloriesChild"];
    var childcalTotal=0;
    //If the totalChild is not blank
    if(totalChild.value!="")
    {
        childcalTotal = parseInt(totalChild.value)*parseInt(caloriesChild.value);
    }
return childcalTotal;
}

function gettotalCalories()
{
    //Here we get the total calories by calling our function
    //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
    var totalCalories = gettotalAdult() + gettotalChild();
    //display the result
    document.getElementById('total-req-cal').innerHTML = "The total required calories are "+totalCalories;
}

</script>
```

This is my HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="totalAdult" id="totalAdult" onkeyup="gettotalCalories()" />
```

This is my error:

> gettotalCalories is not defined

If it helps, the script is in the head of a WordPress page. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This may be a sneaky error - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153909/why-is-my-javascript-function-sometimes-not-defined

Comment: @Adel - Your link is a circular reference.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything specific wrong with what you posted: http://jsfiddle.net/LZVp6/

Comment: Are you sure your script is loading into the page. Have you fired up firebug or chrome's console to see what scripts are loaded?

Comment: `$this->gettotalAdult()` I don't think you can use `->` syntax in JS, can you?

Comment: @Keith - Yes, can see it in Firebug

Comment: @vol7ron - That was from a failed remidy attempt and it's removed now, but not the problem unfortunately

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have `<script type="text/jquery">` you may need `<script type="text/javascript">` instead.

Comment: lol... I think that was it! Now I'm getting a different error: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null, but at least I can start tracing that down now that something is working!

Comment: Just saw this, you beat me to it.

Comment: When I first noticed that, I didn't think that was so important.

Comment: @MichaelDavis you shouldn't change the question... it makes the answer more confusing

Comment: @vol7ron - Good point! I'll edit that... I appreciate all the help! I'm always amazed how responsive everyone is here.