# Ember.js makes my js not working when referenced

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ember.js

I have used `handelbars.js` in my project and now I want to use `Ember.js` also. My problem is that whenever I add the `js` files to my `site.master` some of my `jquery` codes don't work but the others work fine. And when checked it by chrome it says :
`'function'` is not defined.
Here is my reference lines:

```
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/v2/HM.pagination.js"></script>
    <link href="/Content/v2/SiteStyle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/v2/DLoginStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <script src="/Scripts/handlebars.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/ember-1.1.2.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/ember-data.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/js/Search.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm really confused of this problem.

Comment: `fuctiont`, or `function` ?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153909/why-is-my-javascript-function-sometimes-not-defined

Comment: also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676604/javascript-uncaught-reference-error-function-is-not-defined

Comment: Why do you use such an old version of ember?

Comment: @Aristos: the `function` is true and I have just typed wrong here. Thanks for your links, but they didn't work. I mean they didn't point to my problem.

Comment: @Lux I just got it through VS Package Manager console. I hoped it will install the latest version!

Comment: @Yasin its completely outdated! Use at least `1.13`, but I would recommend to use `2.x`! But also I would strongly recommend you to use `ember-cli` if you want to go on the ember route! Otherwise you won't be able to benefit much from the ecosystem.